# Implementing this vector calculus equation?

Tags: matlab, vector, calculus

I am trying to implement the following vector calculus equation in MATLAB.

[image]

Here `n`, `u`, `v` etc are 2D matrix of size `201 X 201` and others like `mu` and `chi` are respective functions. There are few doubts which comes to my mind now. `gradient` command produces both x-component and y-component. So how can I represent grad(n)? Can someone help me to realize this equation?

---

My attempt to code the first component alone in the equation is given below. The code is running inside a loop. I believe this `nx+ny` part in the code is wrong, but I saw such an attempt [here](http://portal.unimap.edu.my/portal/page/portal30/Lecturer%20Notes/KEJURUTERAAN_KOMPUTER/SEM_2_2005_2006/EKT241_TEORI_ELEKTROMAGNET/LABORATORY_MODULES/LAB%202.PDF) in the example section "Part II: Divergence of a Vector Field".

```
    [U,V] = meshgrid(1:201);
    while t<T-dt
      [nx,ny]=gradient(rho(:,:,1),dx,dy);
      [ux,uy]=gradient(u(:,:,1),dx,dy);
      a = divergence(U,V,mu*(nx+ny));
      %b =divergence((U,V,chi*n(:,:,1)*(ux+uy));
      n(:,:,2) = (dt)*(a) + n(:,:,1);
      t=t+dt
      u(:,:,1) = u(:,:,2);
      n(:,:,1) = n(:,:,2);
      rho(:,:,1) = rho(:,:,2);
    end
```

Comment: Do you have some code lines to show us what you already tried ?

Comment: @Peut22 : Yes I will give code as edit.

Comment: Please post reproducible values for all your variables (T, dt, rho, n, and so on).  Then tell us why you think the output values you're getting are wrong.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : OK I will do.